# Move tables to a new database migration Room Android

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using Room in Android for my databases. Recently I had to create an alternate for my main database so now I have 2 databases.

```
abstract class FirstDatabase : RoomDatabase() 
abstract class ScondDatabase : RoomDatabase()
```

I have a table in the `FirstDataBase` that I want to copy to the `SecondDataBase`. I know I should write migration but I don't know how I should do that.
This is my current migration with dagger for room:

```
fun provideDatabaseMigration56(): Migration {
        return object : Migration(DATABASE_VERSION_5, DATABASE_VERSION_6) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pins`")
                
            }
        }
    }

    fun provideDatabaseMigration45(): Migration {
        return object : Migration(DATABASE_VERSION_4, DATABASE_VERSION_5) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pins` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `slug` TEXT NOT NULL)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the SQLite `ATTACH DATABASE` statement. This allows you to attach an additional database to the current connection and then run queries referencing tables within both. There is some detailed documentation [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-attach-database/) which shows the syntax:

```
ATTACH DATABASE file_name AS database_name;
```

You can then run queries referencing tables from both databases, but make sure that when referencing a table from the attached database that you refer to it as

```
database_name.table_name
```

as opposed to just `table_name`.